# Android MPChart resets scrollingX

Tags: java, android, charts, scroll, mpandroidchart

So I have currently worked with the MPChart Library from PhilJay (https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) but I have some problems with my scrolling on the x-Axis because its gonna reset when I try to scroll twice... I do not how how to describe it exactly in words so heres a video from my problem:

https://youtu.be/h04RItDrE34

As you see I cannot scroll far because when I attempt a second scroll the chart instantly starts of there where I started my first scroll, not where I ended it...

Heres my code how I modified the LineChart (should not scrollY):

```
LineChart graphView;

public ECGView(LineChart graphView){
    this.graphView = graphView;

    setup(graphView);
}

public LineChart getGraphView(){
    return graphView;
}

public void addFloatArrayToSeries(float[] floats, int color){
    ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

    int i = 0;
    for(float val : floats){
        entries.add(new Entry(i, val));
        i++;
    }
    LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(entries, "ECG");
    lineDataSet.setColor(color);

    ArrayList<ILineDataSet> lineDataSetif = new ArrayList<>();
    lineDataSetif.add(lineDataSet);
    LineData lineData = new LineData(lineDataSetif);

    graphView.clear();
    graphView.setData(lineData);

}

public void setup(LineChart graphView){
    graphView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(45,45,45));
    graphView.setScaleYEnabled(false);
}
```

and the xml-layout code from Android:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/ecg_box"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:cardElevation="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.13">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/ecg_viewer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself, however the Cardview, my Chart is in, was the problem...